# "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT * 
FROM CODS_NETINV.PHYS_STRUCT
FETCH 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

This should be rather simple, but I get the error in the question title.

Comment: @vaibhavmathur why check the mysql documentation if the question is about Oracle?

Comment: check version and check  manual for proper syntax

Comment: I believe `fetch` needs `first` or `next` after it.

Comment: `fetch` does require `first` or `next` after it, before the number of rows. And it only works in Oracle 12. Are you in fact using Oracle? And if so, is it version 12?

Comment: To check your Oracle version use: `select * from v$version;`

Comment: I was using Oracle 11